# why I load long text in textView does not show me?¿

Tags: android

I use this new thread from a method called from onCreate().
info is a textView().

```
 new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {  
                info.post(new Runnable(){
                     public void run() {
                        info.setText(panel.getInfo());
                     }
                  });
            }
       }).start();
```

If info.setText(panel.getInfo()); call without creating the thread take 3-4 seconds being blocked application but showing it,

then how can I show the text without being blocked the app¿?

Answer (score 0):

```
 new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {  
                String text = panel.getInfo();
                info.post(new Runnable(){
                     public void run() {
                        info.setText(text);
                     }
                  });
            }
       }).start();
```

Actually what is taking long is your panel.getInfo() call. And your a making this call in the info.post, so you're doing it in the UI thread.

Comment: Even using this, nothing still appears in the textView.

Comment: Are you sure panel.getInfo() is giving you a result?

Comment: yes, if even replacing it with res.getString(R.string.txt_house); don't load anything. Also I print a log of text and the text goes well. However if I do not think the thread, I show him the previous block.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I think you should move code `String text = panel.getInfo();` from `info.post` method, because it will be executed at UI thread. Do something like this:

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        String text = panel.getInfo();
        info.post(new Runnable(){
            public void run() {
                info.setText(text);
            }
        });
    }
}).start();
```

Secondly, I think you should save your thread in class member, because GC may destroy your Thread, before it be in time to do something. So, do something like this:

```
mThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            String text = panel.getInfo();
            info.post(new Runnable(){
                public void run() {
                    info.setText(text);
                }
            });
        }
    }).start();
```

Where mThread is a class member:

```
public abstract class MyActivity extends ActionBarActivity{
    private Thread mThread;
    /*Other code*/
}
```